# Finding an $n$-differential form in $\Omega^n \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ that's never zero on $\mathbb{S}^n$.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, differential-forms

Iv'e been struggling with defining an n-form in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ that's never zero on $\mathbb{S}^n$

I know how to define an $n$-form that's never zero in $\mathbb{S}^n$ by defining a function for each map in a finite atlas and summing these functions up, but defining it in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is problematic.
I also know that i need to define a function(diffeomorphism) from $\mathbb{S}^n$ to a representation of $\mathbb{S}^n$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$
$$i: \mathbb{S}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n+1} $$
and for a differential form defined on $\Omega^n \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, $\omega$, $i^*(ω)$ is defined in $\Omega^n \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$

but i dont really have the idea of combining these two concepts together

Comment: Are you trying to write a definition, or just looking for an example of an $n$-form on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ that doesn't vanish on $S^n$? If it's the latter, then why not just take $\omega = dx^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^n$?

Comment: @JeffreyM Note that your example vanishes at every point of the sphere where the tangent plane is parallel to the $x_{n+1}$-axis, i.e., on the equator $x_{n+1}=0$.

Comment: Here's a suggestion: Don't think about atlases. Start with $n=1$ and try to draw a nowhere-zero vector field. Does that give you an idea for a $1$-form? Now, for $n=2$, you can't do it with vector fields, but perhaps you can generalize the pattern you saw for $n=1$.

Comment: @Ted, ah true. My bad.

Comment: Try $\omega = \sum_{j=1}^{n+1} dx^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge \hat{dx^j} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^{n+1}$, where $\hat{dx^j}$ just means that factor is being omitted.

Comment: @JeffreyM You’re thinking too formally with symbols and not enough about geometry. Does $dx+dy$ work on $S^1$?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if [interior products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_product) are something you've learned, but they can help here.

On $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, let:
\begin{align*}
    X &= x^1 \frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}
       +x^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial x^2}
       +\dotsm+ x^{n+1} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{n+1}} \\
    \nu &= dx^1 \wedge dx^2 \wedge \dotsm \wedge dx^{n+1}
\end{align*}
Then the $n$-form $\omega =\iota_X\nu$ is nonzero on $S^{n}$.

Intuitively speaking, $\nu$ is the volume form on $\mathbb{R}^n$ which takes the determinant of the matrix of the components of the $n+1$ vectors. The vector field $X$ is normal to $S^n$. Given $p \in S^n$ and linearly independent tangent vectors $v_1,\dots,v_n$ to $S^n$ at $p$, $\omega(v_1,\dots,v_n) = \nu(X_p,v_1,\dots,v_n)$. Since $X_p,v_1,\dots,v_n$ are linearly independent, $\nu$ of them is nonzero.

You can use the fact that $\iota_X$ is an antiderivation to calculate it explicitly. If you try $n=1$ and $n=2$ you'll see what's going on.

Comment: @Ted That's a good point. I'll change my notation.